# Is there any way we can remove watch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs watches DOM elements,many elements means too much watches created. so is there any way we can remove unneeded watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps :

[Remove Watches in AngularJs](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/)